# What is the proper format for specifying font variations (ie bold, italic) using Google Font Loader?

Tags: javascript, webfonts, google-font-api

I'm using Google Font Loader to load a couple of Google Web Fonts.

I've noticed that when specifying the fonts to load the [suggested format](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader#GoogleModule) of specifying weight in numeric form, doesn't work.  I know that the font load of the bold variant doesn't work because the Google Font Loader inserts *wf-istokweb-n7-inactive*.

**Doesn't Work:**

```
WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: ['Istok Web:400,700'] },
}
```

**Works:**

```
WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: ['Istok Web:400,bold'] },
}
```

Have a look at a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bZEQL/2/).  (NOTE: The jsfiddle is in an iframe so you'll have to dig into the iframe's  tag to see the added classes.)

So is specifying the font weights numerically not the proper way to go?  Or is it an anomaly with this particular font?

Comment: Numerically should be correct, but if only 'bold' works for this particular font for some reason, I'd stick to it.  It does seem to be an issue on Google's end...